# Perform a case sensitive search

Tags: enterprise-architect

is ist possible do perform a case sensitive search in Enterprise-Architect?

I can not find an appropriate filter to set this. 
thx

Comment: Could you please elaborate the task , what you need to achive / problem you are facing , So that we can help you to resolve

Comment: i want to perform a normal search with Strg + F. And i look after a string like UpperLimit. But of course the inbuilt search of EA shows me UPPERLIMIT and upperLimit, too. is this possible to create such a search in the search-Builder or am i not finding the setting for "case-sensitive" - search? :-)

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it Enterprise Architect's internal search just queries the database directly. So unless you are working on Oracle it is going to be case insensitive. The work around is to create your own custom SQL search that is case sensitive.

To do this:

1. Open up the search window (Ctrl+F)
2. Click the new search button
3. Select SQL Editor, enter a name and click OK

The next bit is database dependant but here is a sql server and a mysql example for an exact and fuzzy search - we are using the Collate command:

SQL Server - Exact

```
select *
from t_object
where
t_object.Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'BEEF'
```

MySQL - Fuzzy

```
select *
from t_object
where
t_object.Name COLLATE utf8_bin like 'Corrected%'
```

You will just need to find the COLLATE command that works for your database type.

I hope this helps!

TomO

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I will have a look, at first attempt both are not working. I am running a SQL Server 2008 :-)